# how to iterate through XML param in XSLT

Tags: xslt, msxsl

I have an XML file that I am transforming via XSLT.  I am passing an XML as parameter to the XSLT via C#.  The parameter's name is attachment and it contains XML.  It is written as follows:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
XmlTextWriter w = new XmlTextWriter(sw); 
w.WriteStartElement("root"); 
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sWordFileName)) { 
    w.WriteStartElement("mylink", sWordFileName); 
    w.WriteEndElement(); 
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPDFFileName)) { 
    w.WriteStartElement("mylink", sPDFFileName);
    w.WriteEndElement();
}
w.Close();
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(sw.ToString()));
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
_exportSet[currentExportSet].Format.ParamList["attachment"] = nav.Select("./*");
```

My xml parameter looks like

```
<root><attachment xmlns=file1><attachment xmlns=file2></root>
```

Now in XSLT I need to iterate through this XML param and create a link.

Here is my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
        xmlns:my-scripts="urn:my-scripts" 
        xmlns="factiva.com/fcs/schemas/newsSummaries">

        <xsl:param name="attachment"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$attachment">  
            <a target="_blank" href="#"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></a>  
         </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it doesn't create a link.

Comment: Why are you asking for the reason that your "code" is not working? The actual value of the parameter you clain is passed to the transformation is not even an well-formed XML document -- you should have got an exception at the time you wanted to load this into an XmlDocument. Not to speak about the XSLT stylesheet. The best recommendation is that you need to read and learn at least the basics of XML, XPath and XSLT.

Comment: Now the question is well defined as MS specific XSLT processor. I think that @Dimitre can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XSLT parameter is different than an XML tag name.  Parameters are passed using the  tag as described [here](http://projects.ischool.washington.edu/tabrooks/545/ContentManagement/PassingParameters.htm).

As stated in the comments below, this problem is not too different from what is provided in the link above.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
XmlTextWriter w = new XmlTextWriter(sw); 
w.WriteStartElement("root"); 
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sWordFileName)) { 
    w.WriteStartElement("attachment", sWordFileName); 
    w.WriteAttributeString("name", sWordFileName);
    w.WriteEndElement(); 
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPDFFileName)) { 
    w.WriteStartElement("attachment");
    w.WriteAttributeString("name", sPDFFileName);
    w.WriteEndElement();
}
w.WriteEndElement();
w.Close();
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(sw.ToString()));
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
xslArg.AddParam("attachment","",nav);
```

Here would be XSL to match per [Accessing parameters which contain mark-up](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N5982.html#d8188e46):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
   xmlns:my-scripts="urn:my-scripts" 
   xmlns="factiva.com/fcs/schemas/newsSummaries">
    <xsl:param name="attachment" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$attachment"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="attachment">
        <a target="_blank" href="{@name}">{@name}</a>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:my-scripts="urn:my-scripts"
    xmlns="http://www.factiva.com/fcs/schemas/newsSummaries">

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:my-scripts="urn:my-scripts"
    xmlns="http://www.factiva.com/fcs/schemas/newsSummaries">

<xsl:param name="attachment"/>


       <xsl:for-each select="$attachment">
        <a target="_blank" href="#"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></a>
       </xsl:for-each>

Comment: @jatin - I assume that is your XSL - but beyond that I'm not quite sure what your comments indicate?

Comment: attachment is passed as param and it contains xml like <root><attachment xmlns=file1><attachment xmlns=file2></root> which i need to iterate and display as link

Comment: basically, i am doing XSLT transformation. Now my requirement is, i need to create some links which will be decided runtime. So i programatically create XML and pass it to XML as we don't have array in XSLT

Comment: Ok. I use c#. I have one big XML. let me call it myXML. Now i am applying XSLT on myXML. I need to pass some parameters during XSLT transformation. One of the parameter name is "attachment" which i declare as <xsl:param name="attachment"/> in my XSLT. This parameter value i created by c# and it looks like <root><attachment xmlns=file1><attachment xmlns=file2></root>. Now, i my xslt i need to iterate inside this parameter and create <a> tag

Comment: @jatin - updated based on what I've found, but you may want to add this information to your question so others can answer and possibly change your tags to include C#.

Comment: @jatin - do you get any errors from the parser?  Do you have any debug?

Comment: No. i don't get any errors. do i need to use <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($attachment)">

Comment: @jatin - I'd try it and see.  Usually when debugging a transform I start removing pieces until I see that the transform is working with a minimal set, then add information back in.

Comment: @justkt: It's ok to pass XML node set as parameter. Please, don't confuse people!

Comment: @Alejandro - I understand, I just didn't understand at first why one would do that, because the question at first only showed a small snippet that looked like all the author needed was to transform a small XML string.  The comments here are left from that earlier revision.

Comment: @justkt: Passing a node set as parameter is handy for structured data (like maps).

Comment: this is how i pass param to xslt StringWriter sw  = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter w = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
w.WriteStartElement("root");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sWordFileName))
{
w.WriteStartElement("mylink", sWordFileName);
w.WriteEndElement();
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPDFFileName))
{
w.WriteStartElement("mylink", sPDFFileName);
w.WriteEndElement();
}
w.Close();
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(sw.ToString()));
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
_exportSet[currentExportSet].Format.ParamList["attachment"] = nav.Select("./*");am i doing something wrong

Comment: @jatin - I have added this information to the question, where other answerers can see it.  You should see [@Chris's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095483/how-to-iterate-through-xml-param-in-xslt/5095542#5095542), which corrects your XML and XSLT and may help significantly.  [@Alejandro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095483/how-to-iterate-through-xml-param-in-xslt/5096546#5096546) has presented you a *working* example.

Comment: @justkt: Your code isn't addressing the question as it's not passing a node set parameter. Please, do correct that.

Comment: @Alejandro - I don't know why my answer was accepted, as my comments pointed to your answer and Chris's.  I will address my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It should read `<xsl:for-each select="attachment">...`. There is no `$` sign because `attachment` is the name of an XML element, not a variable.

---

**EDIT after you've given the full XSLT and XML.**

There are several problems with your XML:

- All tags should be closed.
- You may not use the `xmlns` for anything else that it's meant for — namespaces.
- You must have double quotes around the attribute values

So a correct version of the XML file would be (for instance):

```
<root>
  <attachment ptr="file1" />
  <attachment ptr="file2" />
</root>
```

The XSLT file has some issues too:

- The `xsl` namespace should be bound to the exact URI `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`.
- You must have at least a *template* so that the XSLT transform processes your input XML document.

A correct version would be, for instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="attachment">  
      <a target="_blank" href="{@ptr}"><xsl:value-of select="@ptr" /></a>  
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm not sure it is exactly what you want, but for the above document it produces the following fragment:

```
<a target="_blank" href="file1">file1</a>
<a target="_blank" href="file2">file2</a>
```

Comment: @ChrisJ: `attachment` XPath expression would select `attachment` children of context node (parameter reference not used)

Comment: @Alejandro: I've updated the answer after you've added the full XSLT.

Comment: @ChrisJ: Now is better. You wrote: *"You must have at least a template so that the XSLT transform processes your input XML document"*. That's not true. Do test it. Besides that you didn't address the question title.

Comment: @Alejandro: I tested your files (not with C#, with xsltproc), and it sure did not work; the processor reported the aforementioned errors... Please tell us more explicitly what your question is, what the expected result is.

Comment: @ChrisJ: I'm not the OP. @jatin is.

Comment: @Alejandro: oops, sorry about that. Then, jatin, please tell us if this answer helps you, and if not, what you were expecting.

Answer (score 2):

**You can pass any XPath/XSLT data type as parameters**. How to do that entirely depends on the XSLT processor implementation.

As proof this stylesheet, with any input (not used):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="attachment" select="document('parameter.xml')/root"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$attachment"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="attachment">
        <a target="_blank" href="{@href}">Link</a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And `parameter.xml` resource as:

```
<root>
    <attachment href="file1"/>
    <attachment href="file2"/>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<a target="_blank" href="file1">Link</a>
<a target="_blank" href="file2">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to put the value of your attribute that has the link in it like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@YourAttribute"/>
```

This selects an attribute for the current xml element.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is somewhat incorrect. Where are the quotes, what is $attachment?
You probably forgot to mention namespace, to select correctly, you need to write `select="//file1:attachment"` or sth like that.

Comment: attachment is passed as parameter which contains XML